# Duplicated status line in MacVim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, macvim

I am using vim-airline in MacVim. My status line looks OK, but I noticed the original status line in Vim is still there:

[image]

I am wondering how can I remove this line and only keep the vim-airline status bar?

Thanks

Comment: Consider: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/how-to-get-rid-of-the-command-line-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one statusline in your screenshot: the dark bar that is styled by the vim-airline plugin. The message below it is echoed into the *command-line*; it gets overwritten when you enter command-line mode via `:`. You've just `:w`ritten the current file, so you see it mentioned both in the statusline (as the current buffer) and in the command-line (with additional information of how much data was written).

- [`:help 'laststatus'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27laststatus%27) can make the statusline disappear, with an option value of `1` it will only appear when you have more than one window open.
- To avoid the message, you can prepend the command (e.g. `:w`) with `:silent`.
- The message contents (and details) can be tweaked via [`:help 'shortmess'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shortmess%27).
- For completeness, if you want more messages (rather than less), you can increase the height of the command-line via [`:help 'cmdheight'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cmdheight%27).